# Possible flaw in proof that ∃xG(a,x) ⊨ ∀xG(a,x)

Tags: predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I know that ∀xG(a,x) is not true in the general case where the only premise given is ∃xG(a,x), but using the rules for predicate logic in natural deduction, I've managed to deduce ∃xG(a,x) ⊨ ∀xG(a,x) anyway, but I'm unable to see the flaw(s) in my proof. The proof is:

```
1 ∃xG(a,x)                    premise
2 x0: G(a,x0) [x/x0]          assumption
      x0:
3        G(a,x0) [x/x0]       Copy 2
4     ∀xG(a,x)                ∀x i 3-3
5 ∀xG(a,x)                    ∃x e 1,2-4
```

Where am I deducing things incorrectly?

Comment: Going from step 3 to step 4 is wrong. Can you state exactly and precisely which rule you used there?

Comment: Additionally, you're using $\vDash$ when you really mean $\vdash$ (that is, you're using semantic entailment rather than syntactic).

Comment: The rule ∀x i states that if you have a box that assumes a variable x0 and concludes P(x0) [x/x0], you can conclude ∀xP(x).

Comment: I think the mistake is going from 1 to 2. There is no rule (at least if I remember correctly) that allows you to go from $\exists x P(x)$ to $P(x_0)$

Comment: @Max: I'm making an assumption at step 2. I don't see the problem with that.

Comment: @Max You may be right. I am not familiar with the notation used here.

Comment: That rule can only be used if $x_0$ is unbound. In your example, you introduced $x_0$ under special circumstances, rather than just assuming $x_0$ with no other hypotheses. Your proof reads: "suppose there is $x$ such that $G(a,x)$. So let $x_0$ be such that $G(a, x_0)$. Suppose from $x_0$ we may deduce $g(a, x_0)$. Then it is the case that for all $x$, $G(a,x)$. Hence [bogus, since we didn't prove the thing two sentences ago!] for all $x$, $G(a,x)$."

Comment: @Måns Nilsson : thats not the correct way to use $\exists$ in sequent calculus, and I assume it's the same in most (if not all) proof systems. In sequent calculus, if you have the sequents $\Gamma\vdash \exists x, P(x)$ and $\Gamma,P(x_0)\vdash B$ with $x_0$ not free in $B$, then you can infer the sequent $\Gamma\vdash B$. And if I'm not mistaken, it's the only thing you can deduce from $\Gamma\vdash \exists x P(x)$.

Comment: The "generalization rule" that you have used in deriving 4 from 3 has an essential proviso : $\varphi(x) \vdash \forall x \varphi (x)$, provided that $x$ is not free in any assumption. In your derivation, $G(a,x)$ is an assumption and you cannot apply Gen to derive $\forall x G(a,x)$.

Comment: The "trick" of renaming the varibale used in step 2 with $\exists$-elim does not works; in that case, you have to apply Gen to get $\forall y G(a,y)$, and agian the proviso is not satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrong step in the purported derivation of $\exists x G(a,x) \vdash \forall x G(a,x)$ is the "generalization" used in deriving 4 from 3.

In [Natural Deductin](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H7) the $\forall$I rule: $φ(x)⊢∀xφ(x)$ [or: if $\Gamma \vdash φ[a/x]$, then $\Gamma ⊢ ∀xφ(x)$] has the essential proviso: provided that $x$ is not free in any assumption.

In your derivation, $G(a,x)$ is assumed in step 2 and we cannot apply $\forall$I to derive $∀xG(a,x)$.

Regarding the use of $\exists$E in step 2, it is correct; in Natural Deduction the $∃$E rule licenses the derivation of $ψ$ from $∃xφ(x)$ assuming $φ[a/x]$, provided that $y$ is not free in any other assumption nor in $ψ$.